# Tips on making accidental Visual Studio project changes more difficult?

Tags: visual-studio

my team uses Visual Studio for our development environment,  we like it very much

we use the same project files in our automated build

our problem is that it's so easy to make changes in visual studios UX that get applied to the project files.  we're seeing frequent build breaks

...I know...I know...  dont submit them to the repro!

I wish I could convince everyone to be more careful, but lets be honest - it's very easy given the number of permutations {x86,x64,any} {release,debug}

My question:  Is there anything I can add to a VS project that would make it more difficult to make changes?   I'm not looking for a perfect solution, but the UX in VS works great up until a point, and then I'd prefer notepad to keep mistakes down

I could make the file read only, I dont know how that would play with our source control but I could investigate.

I'm hoping for something clever,  maybe a mode that would prompt for confirmation before changing?

ideas / tips?

Comment: If you are using TFS you can create custom checkin policies that inspect files and reject checkins that don't satisfy the policy. We use them because editing EDMX files in VS will change a SQL "2005" value to "2008" but we still need to support 2005 so the changes kept biting us.

Answer (score 1):

Bring a piggy bank to the office. If a user commits a file that breaks the automated build, then that person has to add $1 to the piggy bank. At the end of the project, or when the pot reaches a particular amount, buy something for the team and print up a sheet showing how much each person "contributed" to the pot.

Answer (score 0):

You should check visual studio for options so that check out and check in are explicit.

You can also add [check in policies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181459%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which among other can demand that a clean build was done locally before checking in.

If you would like more help, you should add some information both about your current setup and what you would like to prevent and what you would like achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I usually have the team lead check-out the project file and keep it locked. Then nobody else can check-in changes. It is a little lo-tech, but it worked each time we did it.  A benefit to this approach is that, when a user tries to make a change to the project file, he/she gets a reminder right away (because it can't be checked-out).

If we need changes, the project lead makes the changes, checks-in and out right away.